# Tracking code script in directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, matomo

I'm trying to build a directive to dynamically import the tracking code scripts in my main page:

```
<trackingcode trackingcodevalue="{{padCtrl.trackingnumber}}"></trackingcode>
```

the directive:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('directives.trackingcode', ['pascalprecht.translate', 'ngSanitize'])
  .directive('trackingcode', function () {
    return {

      restrict: 'E',
      //parameter
      scope: {
        trackingcodevalue: '@' //<-- Here
      },

      link: function (scope) { },

      //template definition
      templateUrl: 'directives/trackingcode/trackingcode.html'
    }
  });
}).call(this);
```

and the template:

```
<pre>{{trackingcodevalue | json}}</pre>

<!-- Piwik -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _paq = _paq || [];

  var idnumber = trackingcodevalue;

  //alert(idnumber);

  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  (function () {
    var u = "///piwik/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u + 'piwik.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', idnumber]);
    var d = document, g = d.createElement('script'), s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type = 'text/javascript';
    g.async = true;
    g.defer = true;
    g.src = u + 'piwik.js';
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
  })()
</script>
<noscript><p><img src="//sr03695/piwik/piwik.php?idsite="+idnumber style="border:0;" alt="" /></p></noscript>
<!-- End Piwik Code -->
```

The directive is loading but there is one error and the statistic is not loaded:

> angular.js:12722 ReferenceError: trackingcodevalue is not defined
>       at eval (eval at  (jquery.js:328), :3:18)
>       at Function.jQuery.extend.globalEval (jquery.js:328)
>       at jQuery.fn.extend.domManip (jquery.js:5435)
>       at jQuery.fn.extend.append (jquery.js:5218)
>       at . (jquery.js:5333)
>       at jQuery.access (jquery.js:3491)
>       at jQuery.fn.extend.html (jquery.js:5300)
>       at angular.js:8728
>       at processQueue (angular.js:14991)
>       at angular.js:15007

any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this version.

Is little differrent and move the logic to the link function in the directive.

The directive part

```
angular
        .module('app.sandbox')
        .directive('trackingcode', trackingcode);

        function trackingcode() {
          var directive = {
              restrict: 'E',
              templateUrl: 'trackingcode.directive.html',
              scope: {
                  trackingcodevalue: '=trackingcodevalue'
              },
              link: linkFunc,
          };

          return directive;

          function linkFunc(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
            var idnumber = scope.trackingcodevalue;
            _paq.push(["setDomains", ["*.siteUrl.com","*.siteUrl2.com"]]);
            _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
            _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
            (function() {
            var u="//piwikurl/piwik/";
            _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'piwik.php']);
            _paq.push(['setSiteId',idnumber ]);
            var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'piwik.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
            })();
          }
    }
```

Pay attention to piwikurl

The template

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _paq = _paq || [];
</script>
```

The usage

```
<trackingcode trackingcodevalue="vm.code"></trackingcode>
```

I moved the definition of _paq variable outside the directive cause is execute in async way by piwik.js and if you keep it inside the directive is out of scope.

Tryed myself and works.

In this way you can keep the most part of the js code inside the directive.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

`One Letter Variable`s made your code difficult to read.

Meanwhile `trackingcodevalue` is not defined in the `outermost scope` of your `script tag`. See:

```
<!-- Piwik -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _paq = _paq || [];

    var idnumber = trackingcodevalue; // THIS LINE ASUMES `trackingcodevalue` exists
```

Note that angularjs will not make your variable available in general scope.

If you really need that variable, think of either:

1. Move the `<script>` code into `directive`
2. Read (and may be observe) attribute value `$('trackingcode[trackingcodevalue]').attr('trackingcodevalue')`
3. But I do advice you to prefer [$watch(...)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) or better [$observe(...)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe)

Comment: thanks for your reply, do you mean including the HTML source directly in the directive definition like: template : "<script>scriptcode var idnumber =" + scope.trackingcodevalue+"</script>"?

Comment: No! -- May be just the content of your HTML's `<script>` tag



i.e `var _paq = _paq || [];

  var idnumber = trackingcodevalue;

  //alert(idnumber);

  _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
  _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
  (function () {
    var u = "///piwik/";
    ...
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
  })()`


but in the directive

See this [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) on directives and this [other one](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler) on the angular's HTMLCompiler (specially the part talking about `link.post`)